# Database column with datatype TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE Issue

Tags: oracle, dst

I am running a report from the jasperserver application which is not getting the correct data into the report based on the time i want the data.

The query that is running on the database is fetching the data based on the time see query below.

```
select * from intot where Site = 'LYNDANE' and code = 'RC1' 
and stamp between TO_DATE('2016/09/22 06:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') 
           and TO_DATE('2016/09/22 08:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') order by stamp asc;
```

it is fetching the incorrect data for below time

```
2016/09/22 07:00:00 and 2016/09/22 09:00:00
```

Now when i run the query for one hour back it is fetching the correct data.

```
select * from intot where Site = 'LYNDANE' and code = 'RC1' 
and stamp between TO_DATE('2016/09/22 05:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') 
           and TO_DATE('2016/09/22 07:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') order by stamp asc
```

I checked the intot structure and found that the stamp is of datatype

```
TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
```

I am suspecting that the query i am sending to the DB for running converts the date according to the time zone.

I checked the timezone of the database see below

```
select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
+00:00
```

Is it a way i can amend the query to get the correct data always and do not get affected by the Day light shifting.

Comment: Just a suggestion, may be it is better to use `hh24:mi:ss` format otherwise with `hh:mi:ss` how do you distinguish between `am` and `pm`?

Comment: Solution is Plirkee's answer.

Comment: Tried that but still same result.

Comment: Can you add an actual value from the table (including the full date and time , time zone, etc.), and the output you get form the query that works; and your session time zone?